# My Cache solution to store data before they are sent to the DB is unreliable

Tags: php, mysql, apc

So I have a website with flash games, each time a user gets a answer correct or wrong the values and the timestamps are sent to the database.

I wanted to reduce the number of accesses to the database so I made a solution with APC Cache, where it accumulates the values and it also has a table to store the references between the users and the sessions that have data to send. When the user logs out/in or changes game they are sent to the mySQL DB. For example if the user shuts down the PC without logout the data is stored in cache until he logs in again. But I found out the APC Cache is very unreliable, sometimes it deletes the values without warning.

Is there any PHP cache where I can achieve that, or another similar solution?

Comment: [memcached](http://memcached.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Caches are .. well, they are caches. They're not meant for information that are going to live forever, and will need to be flushed (for write caches) at regular intervals. Both memcached and apc will expire entries when the cache is full (or the TTL expires), and if they didn't, they'd be in-memory databases instead.

Without knowing the details of why you're having trouble storing data directly in the database, you could use a simple table without indices and one row for each entry to store data. The insert time should be negligible, and you can process the data every five / ten / fifteen minutes and move it into its proper location. This will give you more permanence, at least. That's probably the simplest way of doing stuff with the stack you have today.

You can also look into other solutions, such as redis, message queues (rabbit, gearman, etc.) and a whole sleeve of other technologies. The important part is to avoid using technology made for non-permanent data to store permanent data.